# Connect Oracle MAF app to server database

Tags: eclipse, oracle, oracle-maf

I am using eclipse to develop an oracle MAF application. I set up the environment but i need now to connect my app to the oracle database on the server and i don't know how to start. Do i have to use the local sqlite database then sync with the server or connect directly to the server and how to do it?

thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to make a direct database connection MAF. You will have to expose your data in a web service and consume it in your mobile app.

Comment: and how can i do that can you please point out some tutorials!! and thank you for replying

Comment: @user2489592 You can choose any technology you want but Oracle wants you to use Oracle ADF ofcourse.

Answer (score 1):

One option you can consider is to expose the data in the database as a REST Service which you can invoke from a MAF application.
See this presentation on how to use OEPE to build a MAF application that invokes REST services: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pRdLSOVslQg

Hope this helps. Thanks for your interest in OEPE.
-Raghu

Comment: can i upload my  maf android  app on playstore,somewhere i  heard about oracle licence fees like thisper user :120USD
Single User Update and Support:26.40USD
All user Processor :5,800USD
All user Update and support 1,276.00USD.

Comment: if want to upload it on google playstore and as its web application so server on google cloud platform is it valid,can i implement this things with maf

Answer (score 1):

Here is the simple tutorial which describes that how can you make a REST web service in Oracle MAF, deploy it to web logic server using Jdeveloper and access it from your browser. I hope it'll help you:

http://sanjeev-technology.blogspot.in/2014/09/rest-service-on-weblogic-1034.html

Answer (score 0):

Pervasync just released a new version (6.0.2) of its sync framework that supports synchronization of Oracle MAF SQLite databases with central Oracle, MySQL, SQL Server and PostgreSQL databases.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [this sample tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E53569_01/tutorials/tut_jdev_maf_persistance/tut_jdev_maf_persistance.html) which having the step by step explanation.

To make it work, you need to use JDeveloper 12c ([download it from here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/downloads/index.html)). It will contain WebLogic server as well.

In additional you need to have `Android SDK` for `emulator` (or) you can make use of Android device to deploy and run the application.

**For Android Device:**

You can deploy the application into machine and configure the mobile client app using virtual IP of that machine. So that it can be accessed from outside of the network.

**For Emulator:**

you can run the webservice and client in same machine by configuring the webservice IP as `127.0.0.1` this will route your client app into local machine (P.S: `localhost` does't works here)